# How to figured out a % of an unknown

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I suck at math this question will probably be basic for you guys. I work on a commission basis $3$ people in a truck and we split it , 1st person gets $38$% , 2nd gets $37$% , 3rd gets $25$%. I'm trying to figure out if the 2nd person made $151.99$ for a day how do I calculate what the total of all 3 people was.

So $37$% of $x = 151.99$ ?

Comment: First of all, we don't like people who declaire that they ‘suck at maths’ and just give up...

Comment: I'm decent but definitely not at the level of the equations on this site thanks for the negativity though

Comment: Sorry, but we see a lot here... (People wanting us to do their homework etc.) Anyway, you're in the right path!

Comment: I got my answer but yes it's not for homework it's for work to make sure my boss is not ripping off my truck

Answer (score 1):

Minor hint/ guide:

The total is $100$ units.

$37$ units are worth $\$151.99$

how much is $1$ unit worth?

how much are $100$ units worth?

Does this agree with your equation?

Comment: Thank you very much ... I don't know why I didn't think of it that way and I have calculated my answer thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it is to first note how one can compute how much it is $P$% of a number. For example, what is $56$% of 44352? What you do is turn $56$% into $0.56$ (divide the number by $100$) and then multiply by the number.

Because $0.56 \cdot 44352 = 24837.12$, $56$% of $44352$ is $24837.12$.

Now we know that $37$% of the total (let us call it $T$) is $151.99$. So, someone did the maths,

$$T \cdot 0.37 = 151.99$$

and this sets up an equation. Can you solve it?

You want to isolate $T$ on the left so just divide both sides by $0.37$:

$$T = \frac{151.99}{0.37}$$

and then a calculator or a piece of paper will do the rest!

Comment: Yes this helped aswell siongs minor hint made me look at it a different way and I really dedicated up calculating it . Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

$37$% of $T$ (total) is $\$151.99$

$0.37T = \$151.99$

$T = \frac{151.99}{0.37}$

$T = 410.783783784$ which is about $\$410.78$.